# How to match everything before constant string using RegExp in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I'm going insane.

I need to do the following:

Given a string `"sometext<tag>"`, I nee to extract `"sometext"` from that. Now I have two solutions that work in the Firefox console but not in Google Apps script (could use exec or match):

```
(A) string.match(/(^.*?)<[^<]*?>/)
(B) string.match(/^.*?(?=<[^<]*?>)/)
```

Now I read a lot of stackoverflow answers on similar things and in some they say that lookahead is not supported. Fine. That's why I came up with the capturing group one.

Works like a charm in the console but execute it in GAS and it returns null. WTF??

Why is this happening? Does GAS also not support capturing groups?? Any ideas on how to achieve my goal?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Surely there's a lot of solutions, but I'm more curious about the reason. Have you tried escaping the characters you are trying to match? Or declaring the regex with `new RegExp()`?

Comment: neither helps...

Comment: Can you provide the script for replicating `but execute it in GAS and it returns null.`? Because, when `console.log("sometext<tag>".match(/(^.*?)<[^<]*?>/)[1])` and `console.log("sometext<tag>".match(/^.*?(?=<[^<]*?>)/)[0])` using your sample value and regex are run at the script editor of Google Apps Script, the value of `sometext` is returned from both scripts.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help! The thing is: I found another much bigger Problem which means basically everything I did in the last 8 hours or so was for nothing and I have to start new (very fun), so I don't really care any more... I should have gone to bed some 5 hours ago...

Answer (score 1):

```
"sometext<tag>".match(/([^\<]+)\</)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`string.slice(0,string.indexOf('<'));`